# Rails omniauth-facebook unsolved issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-javascript-sdk, omniauth

The current omniauth-facebook seems to have some issues, and I want to know if anyone has answers to them.

First issue was the **invalid credentials** problem. I couldn't log in to my application using the client-side authorization because of this problem. However, this could be solved by downgrading facebook-omniauth to 1.4.0 version. [(reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597130/omniauth-facebook-keeps-reporting-invalid-credentials))

However, now I'm encountering second problem, **NoAuthorizationCodeError**, with the error message:

```
OmniAuth Strategies Facebook NoAuthorizationCodeError 
(must pass either a `code` parameter or a signed request 
(via `signed_request` parameter):
```

this was asked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370056/omniauth-strategies-facebook-noauthorizationcodeerror-must-pass-either-a-code), but the accepted answer advises to actually **upgrade** to 1.4.1 version again, which would make the previous invalid credentials problem occur again. So this is not an option for me.

The `NoAuthorizationCodeError` happens when I try to log into my application inside the Facebook iFrame (searched my app from the app center) via **internet explorer**. Everything works fine on chrome or firefox.  There's also a [github issue](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/56) exactly pinpointing this problem, but no one has come up with an answer yet. I've also tried to downgrade to omniauth-facebook 1.3.0 version, but it made no difference. I also tried to pass in the `signed_request` parameter like follows:

```
window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback', 
{ signed_request: response.authResponse.signedRequest }
```

However, it didn't make any difference (on IE, the error still persists), and I'm not sure if that is the right way to pass in the code as a parameter (how do I check?)

I assume there is no problem with my settings. I would really appreciate any help on this matter.

*UPDATE:*

I upgraded to 1.4.1 version without having invalid credentials problem, but NoAuthorizationCodeError still occurs when I access the application inside Facebook through Internet Explorer. Check my Github [issue](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/110).

**UPDATE:**

I downgraded to 1.4.0 version, and added signedRequest params.

```
<script>
function login() {
  FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback?' + $.param({ signed_request: response.authResponse.signedRequest })
    } 
  }, {scope: 'email,publish_stream,publish_actions'});
}
</script>
```

There are no errors or alerts in the log, and everything works as expected.
However, if I log in within Facebook iFrame through internet explorer, it does not log me in even after the callback phase is initiated. I guess the original problem has been solved but I can't figure out how to debug this when there is not any kind of error message.

**Problem**: When I click "log in with Facebook" inside Facebook iFrame for my application with Internet Explorer, I'm NOT logged in when the authorization process completes. This problem only happens in that specific environment, and I have had hard time trying to figure out why.

```
2013-02-22T01:10:40+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/auth/facebook/callback?signed_request=LONGSTRING" for 200.1.102.103 at 2013-02-22 01:10:40 +0000
2013-02-22T01:10:40+00:00 app[web.1]: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
2013-02-22T01:10:40+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#create_facebook as HTML
2013-02-22T01:10:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"signed_request"=>"LONGSTRING", "provider"=>"facebook"}
2013-02-22T01:10:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = 'facebook' AND "users"."uid" = 'MYUID' LIMIT 1
2013-02-22T01:10:40+00:00 app[web.1]:    (0.8ms)  BEGIN
2013-02-22T01:10:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."name" = 'MYNAME' AND "users"."id" != 3) LIMIT 1
2013-02-22T01:10:40+00:00 app[web.1]:    (0.9ms)  COMMIT
2013-02-22T01:10:40+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://MYAPP.COM
2013-02-22T01:10:40+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
```

Again, in any other environment authorization works perfectly in all browsers. This problem only occurs when I try to **log in within Facebook via Internet Explorer**.

**My Environment**: omniauth-facebook 1.4.0, omniauth 1.1.1, oauth2 0.8.0, Rails 3.2.11

I intentionally downgraded omniauth-facebook from 1.4.1 to 1.4.0 because of the *invalid credentials* error in the latest version.

Comment: I am also faced same problem, after I downgrade the omniauth-facebook gem into the version 1.4.0 problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

make use of  omniauth (1.1.3), oauth2 (0.8.1) and  omniauth-facebook (1.4.1).

You will not get any error with these

Answer (score 0):

`fastcatch` stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120051/why-omniauthstrategiesfacebooknoauthorizationcodeerror-is-not-handled-in-o) SO post with the help of [getting-more-information-from-omniauth-exceptions](http://inside.oib.com/getting-more-information-from-omniauth-exceptions/) that says,

`... OmniAuth strategies [...], if they encounter a problem, call the method fail! and pass in a symbol describing the problem like :invalid_credentials and the exception they encountered. The fail! method ends up calling OmniAuth.config.on_failure and passing in the Rack environment (after doing a few other things like sticking the exception into the environment...`

Comment: Thanks @saurabh, but this doesn't quite solve the stated problem. I know this information already.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are only seeing the issue in Internet Explorer when using an iframe, it may be a P3P problem.

See http://www.slideshare.net/cmercier/things-i-learned-writing-a-facebook-canvas-app
and [Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer):

> Internet Explorer gives lower level of trust to IFRAME pages (IE calls this "third-party" content). If the page inside the IFRAME doesn't have a Privacy Policy, its cookies are blocked (which is indicated by the eye icon in status bar, when you click on it, it shows you a list of blocked URLs).
> ...
> In this case, when cookies are blocked, session identifier is not sent, and the target script throws a 'session not found' error.

Try adding the [rack-p3p](https://github.com/hoopla/rack-p3p) gem and see if it helps!